# Fluid bake explodes and vanishes

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, baking, cache

I bake a fluid, but after a specific frame, the fluid explodes and disappears.

It's completely normal at first, but after the same frame every time, the fluid loses volume and explodes into just a few droplets, and then nothing.

### What I tried

I've tried all kinds of variations to fix it, domain resolution, clearing the cache, turning on resumable and playback, getting rid of collision objects, but despite all of that, the same thing keeps happening and I don't know what to do.

According to my computer, there's still plenty of space for the fluid configuration files to be saved, so I don't think that's the issue.

<sup>Video of what happens. Before everything is working as it should, but after there is no more fluid.</sup> 
[image]

[Here's the full video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/4SuA3qfHesE)

Comment: Could be a bug.

Comment: Does it happen with a new file? Try to delete objects peace by peace so probably some of them cause this, but it really looks like a cache issue. You can also share your simplified file (delete all objects that does not generate the issue) and share via https://blend-exchange.com